# What would be the correct type to use in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create Header component and when I add prop "testId", I get following type. message -->

> Type '{ children: ReactNode; testId: string | undefined; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> ClassAttributes &
> HTMLAttributes'.   Property 'testId' does not
> exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> ClassAttributes &
> HTMLAttributes'

But when I use "id" instead of "testId", I don't get type error, which is weird. I would like to use "testId" for Heading prop and not sure what type I need to assign. What am I missing?
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-leftpad-l3bhj?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";

interface HeadingProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
  headingLevel: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "p";
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  testId?: string;
}

const Heading: React.FunctionComponent<HeadingProps> = ({
  headingLevel: HeadingLevel = "h1",
  children,
  testId
}: HeadingProps) => {
  return <HeadingLevel testId={testId}>{children}</HeadingLevel>;
};

const App: React.FC<{ headingText: string; description: string }> = () => (
  <div>
    <Heading headingLevel="h2" testId="test-heading">
      Hello World!
    </Heading>
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
return <HeadingLevel testId={testId}>{children}</HeadingLevel>;
```

testId is not a valid HTML attribute. You shoud use testId as the Heading prop and use a JSON for custom attributes in the HeadingLevel component.

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";

interface HeadingProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
  headingLevel: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "p";
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  testId?: string;
}

const Heading: React.FunctionComponent<HeadingProps> = ({
  headingLevel: HeadingLevel = "h1",
  children,
  testId
}: HeadingProps) => {
  const attrs = {"testId": testId}
  return <HeadingLevel {...attrs}>{children}</HeadingLevel>;
};

const App: React.FC<{ headingText: string; description: string }> = () => (
  <div>
    <Heading headingLevel="h2" testId="test-heading">
      Hello World!
    </Heading>
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

Comment: Using the code here, I get  <h2 id="test-heading"></h2>, but I want <h2 testId="test-heading"></h2>. I guess I need to find another type other than html attribute then?

Comment: I got it, check out this edit

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your access. You specify `testId` in the interface, but in the implementation you try to access `testingId` which does not match your interface signature. Also, using regular `id` worked because that's a valid attribute for all elements. Here's the corrected code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";

interface HeadingProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> {
  headingLevel: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "p";
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  testId?: string;
}

const Heading: React.FunctionComponent<HeadingProps> = ({
  headingLevel: HeadingLevel = "h1",
  children,
  testId // typo was here
}: HeadingProps) => {
  return <HeadingLevel>{children}</HeadingLevel>;
};

const App: React.FC<{ headingText: string; description: string }> = () => (
  <div>
    <Heading headingLevel="h2" testId="test-heading">  {/* typo was here */}
      Hello World!
    </Heading>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: I still get type error on typeId with above code. Is there a way add non-html attribute  type to interface?

Comment: I can't reproduce your type error with the code @JudoboyAlex Maybe check the typescript playground link or re-copy the code?